# Foursquare developer how to get the event_id by searching a place name

Tags: foursquare

Hello I was looking a way to get the event id by searching from a place name . I could not find a method in four square API to show it . Can any one help? I want to search by a place name and get the number of checkins not by providing longitudes and latitudes .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should search for the venue using [/venues/search](https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/venues/search). Once you've found the venue you're looking for, you can retrieve its events using [/venues/events](https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/venues/events)

Comment: Venues and Venues events need a VENUE_ID um looking for a way to search by name

Comment: /venues/search returns the venue ID for each returned venue